# Proving an estimate of SDE process under local Lipschitz continuity while the linear growth

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

$X_t$ is a process defined by an SDE:

$d X_t=\mu\left(t, X_t\right) d t+\sigma\left(t, X_t\right) d B_t$

Under the global Lipschitz continuity and linear growth conditions, suppose that $E\left[\|\xi\|^{2 p}\right]$ is finite for some $p \geq 1$. Show that for any finite $T>0$, there exists a constant $C$, depending only on $K, T, p$, such that
$$
E\left[\sup _{0 \leq t \leq T}\left\|X_t\right\|^{2 p}\right] \leq C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^{2 p}\right]\right) .
$$

Does this estimate still hold if global Lipschitz continuity is replaced by local Lipschitz continuity while the linear growth condition remains unchanged?

Hint: Use the following vector inequality $\left(\left|a_1\right|+\cdots+\left|a_n\right|\right)^{2 p} \leq n^{2 p}\left(\left|a_1\right|^{2 p}+\cdots+\left|a_n\right|^{2 p}\right)$.

A related theorem and conclusions are:

***Theorem (existence of strong solutions)***. Suppose $\mu, \sigma$ satisfy the global Lipschitz and linear growth conditions
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \|\mu(t, x)-\mu(t, y)\|+\|\sigma(t, x)-\sigma(t, y)\| \leq K\|x-y\|, \\
& \|\mu(t, x)\|^2+\|\sigma(t, x)\|^2 \leq K^2\left(1+\|x\|^2\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
for every $t \geq 0$ and $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\xi$ be a $\mathbb{R}^n$ random vector, independent of $B$, and with finite second moment $E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]<\infty$. Then there exists a continuous, adapted process $X$ which is a strong solution of equation (1) with initial condition $\xi$. Moreover, this process is squareintegrable: for any finite $T>0$, there exists a constant $C$, depending only on $K$ and $T$, such that
$$
E\left[\left\|X_t\right\|^2\right] \leq C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]\right) e^{C t}, 0 \leq t \leq T .
$$

Remark 1. Global Lipschitz continuity implies linear growth. To see this, just set $y=0$ in the Lipschitz continuity condition and we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|\mu(t, x)\| & \leq\|\mu(t, 0)\|+K\|x\|, \\
\|\sigma(t, x)\| & \leq\|\sigma(t, 0)\|+K\|x\| .
\end{aligned}
$$

If we replace global Lipschitz continuity by local Lipschitz continuity in Theorem 2 while keeping the other conditions, the conclusions of Theorem 2 still hold (Friedman (1975), Chapter 5, Theorem 2.2). The proof is based on localizing the initial condition and $\mu(t, x)$ and $\sigma(t, x)$.

In class I learned about the proof of the global Lipschitz + linear growth version as below, and I tried to replicate that but I'm not quite sure how these conditions play a role, especially when changing to local Lipschitz:

For $0 \leq t \leq T$,
$$E\left[\left\|x_t^{(k+1)}\right\|^2\right] \leqslant 9 E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]+9 K^{\top} \int_0^t\left(1+E\left[\left\|X_s^{(k)}\right\|^2\right]\right) ds$$

Let $$C=\max (9,9 T K^2, 9 T^2 K^2 ).$$ we have

$$E\left[\left\|X_t^{(k)}\right\|^2\right] \leqslant C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]\right)+C \int_0^t E\left[\left\|X_s^{(k)}\right\|^2\right] d s$$

$$\leqslant C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]\right)+C \cdot C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]\right) t$$

$$+C \int_0^t C \int_0^1 E\left[\left\|X_u^{(k-1)}\right\|^2\right] d u d s$$

Applying the estimate repeatedly

$$\leqslant C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]\right)\left(1+ C t+\cdots+\frac{(C t)^{k+1}}{(k+1) !}\right)$$

$$\leqslant C\left(1+E\left[\|\xi\|^2\right]\right) e^{C t}$$

Comment: what have you tried/

Comment: I updated my trial before but I still have no idea.

Comment: please let us know if it does, so that we can mark this answered.

Comment: I think they have the same spirit, but they're not the same question and cannot answer completely. Firstly my question is for strong solution, secondly that question use martingale property and linear growth only, neither local nor global Lipschitz conodition. I guess that's why it's about weak solution and mine is more about strong solution.

Comment: every strong solution is a weak solution. So I am not sure what your question is. To get the estimate you asked, it suffices to use linear growth and continuity. Or did you want something more?